# Firebug Lite on iPad doesn't detect and log JavaScript errors

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad, firebug-lite

I use [Firebug Lite](https://getfirebug.com/firebuglite) in order to debug an app for iPad. 
It works great and I can see CSS files, JavaScript files and inspect the DOM tree directly on the iPad.

However, it seems that it doesn't detect JavaScript errors and do not log them to the console. The default iOS safari console says there are JavaScript errors but Firebug does not detect nor show them. My iPad runs under iOS 5 by the way.

Any ideas ?

Comment: same problem here... have you figured out a solution?